# Python patched mock not respected

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I've encountered an issue while testing a piece of Python code that I just cannot make sense of. In the following code, I test a module's method that should return a 200 when a submission is found and a 404 when a submission is not found. The method that gets a submission is external to the module I am testing so it must be mocked out in the test.

When the below code runs, the second test fails because the status code returned is 200. When I print `analysis_result` it prints the mocked out value for `get_single_submission` supplied in the first test. If I comment out the first test, the test suite passes just fine. I'd appreciate any ideas or input people may have!

Test code:

```
class AnalysisTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        pass

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    @mock.patch('lib.retention.Submissions')
    @mock.patch('lib.retention.Analysis')
    def test_analysis_get_submission(self, mock_Analysis, mock_Submissions):
        mock_Submissions.return_value.get_single_submission.return_value = Submission(
            md5="md5",
            analyze_completed="01-23-12"
        )

        from api import analysis
        test_event = {
            "pathParameters": {
                "query": ["test"],
                "id": 1
            }
        }

        analysis_result = analysis.analysis_get(test_event)
        print(analysis_result)

        self.assertEqual(analysis_result["statusCode"], 200)

    @mock.patch('lib.retention.Submissions')
    @mock.patch('lib.retention.Analysis')
    def test_analysis_get_submission_not_found(self, mock_Analysis, mock_Submissions):
        mock_Submissions.return_value.get_single_submission.return_value = None

        from api import analysis
        test_event = {
            "pathParameters": {
                "query": ["test"],
                "id": 1
            }
        }

        analysis_result = analysis.analysis_get(test_event)
        print("not found")
        print(analysis_result)

        self.assertEqual(analysis_result["statusCode"], 404)
```

And pytest result:

```
@mock.patch('lib.retention.Submissions')
@mock.patch('lib.retention.Analysis')
def test_analysis_get_submission_not_found(self, mock_Analysis, mock_Submissions):
    mock_Submissions.return_value.get_single_submission.return_value = None

    from api import analysis
    test_event = {
        "pathParameters": {
            "query": ["test"],
            "id": 1
        }
    }

    analysis_result = analysis.analysis_get(test_event)
    print("not found")
    print(analysis_result)
```

> ```
>   self.assertEqual(analysis_result["statusCode"], 404)
> ```
>
> E       AssertionError: 200 != 404

```
api/tests/analysis_test.py:72: AssertionError
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
not found
{'statusCode': 200, 'isBase64Encoded': False, 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 'body': '{\n "metadata": {\n  "md5": "md5",\n  "analyzed_date": "01-23-12"\n }\n}'}
```

UPDATE:
File structure

```
project/lib/retention.py
       /api/analysis.py
           /tests/analysis_test.py
```

UPDATE 2:
I printed out `Submissions` in `analysis_get` and found the same mock is being used by both tests somehow

```
<MagicMock name='Submissions' id='4599620440'>
```

Comment: Sure `lib.retention` is the correct path? In your code you have `from api import analysis`.

Comment: Yes, lib.retention.Submissions is an imported module in api.analysis, thus, it needs to be mocked out when used.

Comment: Can you add a minimal tree for you src files to better understand the imports ? Also if you are importing the `api.analysis` module then the lib is `api.analysis.lib.retention`

Comment: Updated with the file structure. `lib` is not a submodule of `analysis` both are submodules of the root project folder.

Comment: As @vin says, if you have and `import lib.retention` in your `api.analisys` then you have to patch `api.analysis.lib.retention.Whatever`

Comment: `lib` is not a submodule of `api.analysis`

Comment: @crawfobw Can you show the code for `analysis.analysis_get`? Are you sure that function is not statefull (e.g. caching, etc)?

Comment: Within the `analysis.py` file `Submissions.__init__` is invoked outside of a function definition at the top of the file. Shouldn't this not matter though because each test has its own `from api import analysis` statement?

Comment: Actually, you're right @a_guest, the `analysis` module is only being imported once by this code. Follow up question, how do I get each test to import its own `analysis` into its scope?

Comment: @crawfobw That's not what you want to do, the imported modules are cached in `sys.modules`. You could remove them or reload via `importlib.reload` but this is no good design. Better create a dedicated class and then each test can create an instance of the class.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @a_guest! Wrapping the code to be tested in a class would be a better design I agree, just posted the answer as is to help those who cannot refactor in such a way address the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in the above code is that I assumed each test could import its own fresh version of the `analysis` module by stating `from api import analysis` in each test. In reality, this only imports `analysis` the first time and not subsequently. Because of the single import, only the first mock_Submissions was being patched into the class as `Submissions` is a stateful component in the `analysis` module. The solution is to edit the code to use the `reload` package to reload imports in each test.

```
from importlib import reload
class AnalysisTest(unittest.TestCase):

@classmethod
@mock.patch('lib.retention.Submissions')
@mock.patch('lib.retention.Analysis')
def setUpClass(cls):
    from api import analysis

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    pass

def setUp(self):
    pass

def tearDown(self):
    pass

@mock.patch('lib.retention.Submissions')
@mock.patch('lib.retention.Analysis')
def test_analysis_get_submission(self, mock_Analysis, mock_Submissions):
    mock_Submissions.return_value.get_single_submission.return_value = Submission(
        md5="md5",
        analyze_completed="01-23-12"
    )

    from api import analysis
    reload(analysis)
    test_event = {
        "pathParameters": {
            "query": ["test"],
            "id": 1
        }
    }

    analysis_result = analysis.analysis_get(test_event)
    print(analysis_result)

    self.assertEqual(analysis_result["statusCode"], 200)

@mock.patch('lib.retention.Submissions')
@mock.patch('lib.retention.Analysis')
def test_analysis_get_submission_not_found(self, mock_Analysis, mock_Submissions):
    mock_Submissions.return_value.get_single_submission.return_value = None

    from api import analysis
    reload(analysis)
    test_event = {
        "pathParameters": {
            "query": ["test"],
            "id": 1
        }
    }

    analysis_result = analysis.analysis_get(test_event)
    print("not found")
    print(analysis_result)

    self.assertEqual(analysis_result["statusCode"], 404)
```